# Adding Click-to-call widget Voximplant for websites

Tags: voximplant

I want to add a Click-to-call widget to my website and heard that Voximplant has a ready solution for websites. How do I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Voximplant has a complete step-by-step guide how to create such a widget:
https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/solutions/clicktocall

Just follow the steps and you're done.